# Is this a mistake $\int_{0}^{1}[(1-x^r)^{n/r}-nx^{n-1}(1-x^r)^{1/r}] \mathrm dx=0?$

Tags: integration

Can anyone show that,
$$\int_{0}^{1}[(1-x^r)^{n/r}-nx^{n-1}(1-x^r)^{1/r}] \mathrm dx=0\tag1$$
Suppose $\ n\ $ and $\ r\ $ are integers.

I can't understand why it should be zero.

making a basic substitution:

$u=1-x^r$

$\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm du}{r(1-u)}$

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{n/r}-n\cdot u^{1/r}(1-u)^{(n-1)/r}}{r(1-u)}\mathrm du$$

Comment: If $u = 1-x^r$, shouldn't we have that $du = - rx^{r-1} dx$? (Among other apparent algebraic errors made as a result.)

Comment: This is what Wolfram Mthematica sais for $n=r=1,\cdots,10$:
$$\left\{0,\frac{2}{15},\frac{6}{35},\frac{604}{3315},\frac{1465}{8008},\frac{1780806}{9915815
   },\frac{179578}{1028775},\frac{503764952}{2982654675},\frac{1389368691}{8517311792},\frac
   {13408371543230}{85149208697553}\right\}$$

Comment: In fact, if we denote the integral as $I(r,m)$, Wolfram Mathematica says that $I(1,m)=0$ and if $r>1$, $$I(r,m)=\frac{(-1)^{m/r} (r-1)^{\frac{m+r}{r}}+1}{m+r}-\frac{m \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{r}\right)
   \Gamma \left(\frac{m}{r}\right)}{r^2 \Gamma \left(\frac{m+r+1}{r}\right)}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $\beta$integral and Gamma functions:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function
Take $x=\sin^{2/r} t$ $$I_1=\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^r)^{n/r} dx=\frac{2}{r}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n/r+1}t ~~\sin^{2/r-1}t~dt=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\Gamma(n/r+1)\Gamma(1/r)}{\Gamma(n/r+1/r+1)}$$
$$\implies I_1=\frac{n}{r^2}\frac{\Gamma(n/r)\Gamma(1/r)}{\Gamma(n/r+1/r+1)}~~~~(1)$$
$$I_2=\int_{0}^{1} nx^{n-1}(1-x^r)^{1/r} dx=\frac{2n}{r}\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n/r-1} t \cos ^{2/r+1} dt=\frac{n}{r}\frac{\Gamma(n/r) \Gamma(1/r+1)}{\Gamma(n/r+1/r+1)}$$
$$\implies I_2=\frac{n}{r^2}\frac{\Gamma(n/r)\Gamma(1/r)}{\Gamma(n/r+1/r+1)}~~~~(2).$$
Hence $$I_1=I_2 \implies I=I_1-I_2=0$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is an elementary solution: Let $y = (1 - x^{r})^{1/r}$. In other words, $x^r + y^r = 1$. Then

\begin{align*}
\int_{x=0}^{x=1} (1 - x^r)^{n/r} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{x=0}^{x=1} y^n \, \mathrm{d}x
= \Bigl[ y^n x \Bigr]_{x=0}^{x=1} - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} x \, \mathrm{d}(y^n) \\
&= - \int_{x=0}^{x=1} n y^{n-1} x \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

Now using that $x = (1 - y^r)^{1/r}$, and noting that $x = 0$ (resp. $x=1$) implies $y=1$ (res.p $y=0$) the above integral is equal to

\begin{align*}
- \int_{y=1}^{y=0} n y^{n-1} (1 - y^r)^{1/r} \, \mathrm{d}y
= \int_{y=0}^{y=1} n y^{n-1} (1 - y^r)^{1/r} \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

Since the name of the dummy variable is irrelevant for the value of the integral, this tells that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} (1 - x^r)^{n/r} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{1} n x^{n-1} (1 - x^r)^{1/r} \, \mathrm{d}x $$

and therefore the integral in question is zero.

---

*Addendum.* The above computation is best understood if one is familiar with the concept of line integral. If one wants to stick to single-variable flavor, the above computation can be rephrases as follows:

Define $\varphi(x) = (1 - x^{r})^{1/r}$. Then it is straightforward to check that $\varphi(\varphi(x)) = x$, i.e., $\varphi$ is its own inverse. Then by substituting $y = \varphi(x)$, or equivalently, $x = \varphi(y)$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} \varphi(x)^n \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{\varphi(0)}^{\varphi(1)} y^n \varphi'(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \Bigl[ y^n \varphi(y) \Bigr]_{1}^{0} - \int_{1}^{0} n y^{n-1} \varphi(y) \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_{0}^{1} n y^{n-1} \varphi(y) \, \mathrm{d}y.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

$$I_1=\int_0^1(1-x^r)^{n/r}$$
$u=x^r\Rightarrow du=rx^{r-1}dx\therefore dx=\frac{du}{rx^{r-1}}=\frac{du}{ru^{(r-1)/r}}$ and so:
$$I_1=\frac1r\int_0^1u^{(1-r)/r}(1-u)^{n/r}du$$

---

$$I_2=n\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x^r)^{1/r}dx$$
$$I_2=\frac nr\int_0^1u^{(n-1)/r}u^{(1-r)/r}(1-u)^{1/r}du$$
$$I_2=\frac nr\int_0^1u^{(n-r)/r}(1-u)^{1/r}du$$
both can be expressed in terms of the beta function (and then the gamma function) and you have $I=I_1-I_2$